# Dynamically create reactive FormGroup Arrays depending upon the value of another FormControl value in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

My initial FormGroup contains some FormControls and a FormArray, which should populate FormGroups dynamically

```
  myForm: formBuilder.group({
     ....
    noOfSomething: ['', Validators.required],
    something:  this.formBuilder.array([])
  }),
```

I can create a FormGroup inside the Form array by a addButton and remove it by a remove button.

but my requirement is when the value of "noOfSomething"(which  is a number) changes ,than according to the value of "noOfSomething" that many form group should be added to the FormArray. and the I can fill of the FormGroups inside of that FormArray.

I am not sure how to initialize it and loop through it in the template.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you can look at the following example.

https://book-monkey2.angular-buch.com/iteration-7/i18n/admin

The Source Code is avaible on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

In a Reactive Form, you can know when a field change using AFTER create the form subscribing to valueChanges, e.g.

```
myForm.get('noOfSomething').valueChanges((value:any)=>
{   let controls:FormGroup[]=[]
    for (let i=0;i<value;i++)
    {
       controls.push(this.formBuilder.group(
         {uno:0
          dos:0
        }) 
    }
    myForm.get('something')=this.formBuilder.array(controls)
})
```

Comment: thanks for your replay, sorry for the confusion about my requirement. somehow with your suggestion i did push the formgroup to the array . but my requirement is different. when the value of something is  4 then no of formgroup should be 4 but when i change the value to 1 then there should be 1 formgroup